# how to post link to all my Facebook pages in the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So what i need is share link to my Facebook pages (3 or 4 pages) my problem is when i click in Share button i get 3 popup, but what i want is one popup to share my link in all pages or a checkbox to choose  which page i want.

this is my code :

```
$('#actionfb').click(function () {
          FB.login(function (response){
          FB.api('/me/accounts',function(apiresponse){

          var data=apiresponse['data'];
          console.log("data :"+data);
          var ids = new Array();
          for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          ids[i]=data[i].id;
          FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: $('#lien').val(),
            description: message,                
            from : ids[i],
          }, function(response){});
          }
          console.log("ids :"+ids);
          });

          },{scope:'manage_pages'});
        });
```

So please if someone has any idea how can i do that i will be very appreciative

Comment: Don't spam. Sharing the same thing to several pages at the same time I would call spam

Comment: Thnx for u're comment, but it's not a spam those are my own pages

Comment: Why can't it be spam because it is your own pages?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed spammy, but there is one way to do this:

Use `FB.api('/page-id/feed')` for posting.

Not tested, but i guess it is easy to understand.

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

Btw, you would not need manage_pages, but publish_actions.